# iphone - The purple location triangle does not go after calling stopUpdatingLocation

Tags: iphone, ios

I am calling the following code when my app moves to the background -

```
[m_coreLocationMan stopUpdatingLocation];
```

However, the purple triangle still stays there. Do I need to do something else as well to make it go?

Comment: Are you sure this code is invoked?

Comment: Yes, I set a breakpoint there and it is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, quite simply, a very regularly occurring OS bug. We noticed this during testing of a large location-aware app. I've personally seen it happen quite often during normal everyday use with different apps.

Answer (score 0):

No. Do you see that on the simulator? Device? What Xcode are you using? Try different simulators and on the device. In some combinations it may not work properly (betas, and some other things that can't be discussed here...)

Comment: I see it on the device. I use Xcode 4 and iOS5. But the same behavior is also on iOS4. I do not see the triangle at all on the simulator.

Comment: It may be related to this. What OS do you have on your device? Also iOS5? CoreLocation was slightly broken on some releases, also depends on your Mac OS (go over the release notes of your xcode release maybe). In any case, I think it would be safer to ask this question at the Apple's dev forums since it's pre released. To your original question - stopUPdatingLocation should turn off location services, hence remove the location symbol.

Comment: Like I said, I notice this behavior not just on iOS5, but also on iOS 4.3, iOS 4.0, so basically every device I have tried the code on.

Answer (score 0):

As I asked [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710861/location-indicator-persists-on-status-bar-after-stopupdatinglocation-is-called/10191560#10191560), did you try to also stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges ? It worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I did try it. It is a bug which we logged on the Apple site and they have acknowledged it. Will be posting an update when they release a solution.