# Location indicator persists on status bar after stopUpdatingLocation is called, but only for old Bundle Identifier

Tags: xcode, ios5, cllocationmanager

Does any one know why the location indicator stay on for certain bundle identifer vs. the others?
I am using an Apple sample LocateMe app, installed on my iOS device running version 5.0.1. When I'm using an old bundle identifier, the location indicator stays on the status bar, after the CLLocationManager  stopUpdatingLocation is being call.

But, when I'm using the same exact app, with the only difference being a new bundle id, the app works as expected and the location indicator disappear once the stopUpdatingLocation is being called.

Did anyone experience this problem or can explain it?

Comment: Do you have any code to post?

Comment: You can find the [LocateMe](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app on Apple Developer website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured that if I reset the Location Warnings from the Settings, the bug disappear.

From your iOS Settings select General | Reset | Reset Location Warnings. This will reset the warning to all the apps. This mean that the next time you start an app that requires location, the iOS will prompt you with the location permission dialog.
Select 'Reset Warnings' from the action sheet.

When running the app again, the iOS will prompts you with the location permission dialog (if it doesn't - repeat the process above to reset the location warnings). After selecting yes, the app behaves as expected, and the location indicator disappears after few seconds.

Comment: This bug is still present in iOS6. Thanks for the solution, that works for me on iOS5 and iOS6.

Comment: Gilad, you sir are my new hero. I've been fighting with this dang thing for most of the day! @emrys57, I too can confirm this bug does still existing in iOS 6... :/

Comment: This is very weird, but after try everything, reset the warnings was also my solution, and I'm using iOS 7.1 with Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to also stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges ? It worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I did try stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and it does not work. The different behavior depends on the BundleId