# Location Status Bar Icon Won't Disappear - MKMapView - iOS 6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location

I have a class which contains an instance of `MKMapView`

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *ibMapView;
```

While I do also use a singleton instance of `CLLocationManager` in other places in the project, I've found that this map view is responsible for the "Location" icon showing on the iPhone status bar.

Specifically, this code is to blame:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // If I comment out this line below, the "Location" status icon never shows, as expected 
    self.ibMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    // ...other magical stuff happens here, not related to map view
}
```

I've tried setting `showsUserLocation` to NO like this

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.ibMapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

    // I also have tried logging to make sure showUserLocation is set to NO- returns "NO" as expected
    DebugLog(@"Show User Location: %@", self.ibMapView.showsUserLocation ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    // ...other stuff happens here, not related to map view...
}
```

However, the location status icon still shows... it never turns off, even after an hour has passed...

How can I get the location status icon caused by setting `showUserLocation` to YES on an `MKMapView` instance to go away?

Comment: does '- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated' getting called? have you tried any logs inside '- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated'

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, `viewWillDisappear:` is called, as verified by putting logs inside it (see updated question).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this is a bug in Apple's frameworks somewhere...

See this question and the selected answer for a solution:

[Location indicator persists on status bar after stopUpdatingLocation is called, but only for old Bundle Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710861/location-indicator-persists-on-status-bar-after-stopupdatinglocation-is-called)

Essentially, if you **Reset Location & Privacy** (Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy), this fixes the issue (as long as you also make sure that you set `showsUserLocation` to NO once you're done it with).